# Preventing trailing slash causes infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a folder `www.example.com/page1/` that stores the content for `www.example.com/page1`. If `page1` does not exist, I would like my custom `404 page` to handle the generation of `page1`, therefore it is essential I do not have a `/` at the end of the url, or at the end of any url. I have tried answers for similar question, but they result in an infinite loop. How can I prevent the trailing slash and the infinite redirect loop?

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301, L]
```

,

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

,

```
Options -Multiviews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
```

,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now. The code used to hide the page extension was causing the infinite loop.